# Given pairs of Number create all chain set possible

Tags: c++, math, set

We have given different pairs of number. Now we have to create a chain that if any element of pair1 is equal to any element of pair2 then they belong to same set.

Example:-

given pairs:

```
(0,1)
(2,3)
(5,4)
(3,5)
(7,6)
(8,7)
```

So all the set are

```
{0,1}, {2,3,4,5}, {6,7,8}
```

How can we achieve this. I am out of thought on this. Any help would be appreciated.

***Solution*** 
**C Code**
    #include

```
#define SIZE 100100

int visited[SIZE];



struct adjListNode{
    int dest;
    struct adjListNode* next;
};

struct adjList{
    struct adjListNode* head;
};

struct Graph{
    int V;
    struct adjList* array;
};

struct adjListNode* newAdjListNode(int dest){
    struct adjListNode* newNode = (struct adjListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct adjListNode));
    newNode->dest = dest;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    return newNode;
}


struct Graph* createGraph(int V){
    struct Graph* graph = (struct Graph*)malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
    graph->V = V;

    graph->array = (struct adjList*)malloc(V * sizeof(struct adjList));

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < V; i++){
        graph->array[i].head = NULL;
    }

    return graph;
}

void addEdge(struct Graph* graph, int src, int dest){
    struct adjListNode* newNode = newAdjListNode(dest);
    newNode->next = graph->array[src].head;
    graph->array[src].head = newNode;

    newNode = newAdjListNode(src);
    newNode->next = graph->array[dest].head;
    graph->array[dest].head = newNode;
}

void printGraph(struct Graph* graph)
{
    int v;
    for (v = 0; v < graph->V; ++v)
    {
        struct adjListNode* pCrawl = graph->array[v].head;
        printf("\n Adjacency list of vertex %d\n head ", v);
        while (pCrawl)
        {
            printf("-> %d", pCrawl->dest);
            pCrawl = pCrawl->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void DFS(struct Graph* graph, int v){
    if(visited[v] == 0){
        visited[v] = 1;
        printf("%d --> ", v);
        struct adjListNode *pCrawl = graph->array[v].head;
        while(pCrawl){
            if(visited[pCrawl->dest] == 0){
                DFS(graph, pCrawl->dest);
            }
            pCrawl = pCrawl->next;
        }
    }
}



int main(void) {
    int V = 5, I, src, dest, i, count = 0;
    scanf("%d %d", &V, &I);
    memset(visited, 0, SIZE);
    struct Graph* graph = createGraph(V);
    while(I--){
        scanf("%d %d", &src, &dest);
        addEdge(graph, src, dest);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < V; i++){
        if(visited[i] == 0){
            count++;
            DFS(graph, i);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    // print the adjacency list representation of the above graph
    printGraph(graph);
    printf("Countries :- %d", count);

    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

`10 8
0 1
2 3
1 4
5 6
7 8
9 7
1 7
3 5`

**Output**

```
SET :: 0 --> 1 --> 7 --> 9 --> 8 --> 4 --> 
SET :: 2 --> 3 --> 5 --> 6 --> 

 Adjacency list of vertex 0
 head -> 1

 Adjacency list of vertex 1
 head -> 7-> 4-> 0

 Adjacency list of vertex 2
 head -> 3

 Adjacency list of vertex 3
 head -> 5-> 2

 Adjacency list of vertex 4
 head -> 1

 Adjacency list of vertex 5
 head -> 3-> 6

 Adjacency list of vertex 6
 head -> 5

 Adjacency list of vertex 7
 head -> 1-> 9-> 8

 Adjacency list of vertex 8
 head -> 7

 Adjacency list of vertex 9
 head -> 7
Sets :- 2
```

Comment: Your example reorders them as well... What have you tried? A naive solution would be just to loop through them all and compare and then store in another structure but have you even tried that?

Comment: Yeah I tried that. But using a naive solution we have to search through all elements every time. which will be O(n^2). and also have to mark each pair if it already inserted or not.

Comment: Then mention that in your question so that there is context of what you have tried. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can represent the numbers as graph vertices. The pairs would be edges. Now all you need to do is run a bfs to count the connected parts.

Comment: In the end simple old dfs saved my life. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Union-find algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) is very effective to solve this problem (your example doesn't build chains, only sets)

Comment: I have tried using the Union-find algorithm after your suggestion. But unable to acheive the expected result.Having pairs <code> 0 1
1 3
2 3I have tried using the Union-find algorithm after your suggestion. But unable to acheive the expected result.Having pairs  (0, 1)
(1, 3)
(2, 3)
(0, 4)
(5, 6)
(7, 8) and getting the parents array {1 3 3 4 -1 6 -1 8 -1}

Comment: My major task is to find the size of each set.

Comment: This is parents array I have got for your pair set in comment: {0 0 0 0 0 5 5 7 7} and for main post: {0 0 2 2 2 2 7 7 7}

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 100100

int parents[100100];

int find(int parent[], int i)
{
    if (parent[i] == -1)
        return i;
    return find(parent, parent[i]);
}
  

void Union(int parent[], int x, int y)
{
    int xset = find(parent, x);
    int yset = find(parent, y);
    parent[xset] = yset;
}

int main(void) {
 int N, I, a, b, i, j, count, temp;
 memset(parents, -1, SIZE);
 scanf("%d %d", &N,&I);
 while(I--){
  scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
  Union(parents, a, b);
 }
 for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
  printf("%d ", parents[i]);
 }
 return 0;
}

Comment: My Program for Union find. Where i am doing wrong??And How you are getting above as parent array. Can you please explain in detail.

Comment: Look at the code from Sedgewick book (chapter 1). http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/Algs3.cxx1-4/code.txt It is mainly the same problem as yours. p and q at every step is your pair, id - parents array